# How to display column titles instead of column IDs in Kendo grid's validation message?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

As I can see, all examples on Kendo UI's site uses column ID. So, if we have 
column like:

```
{
   field:"DocumentID",
   title:"Id of document"
}
```

then validation message looks like "DocumentID required", but i want to get "Id of document required". How can I reach it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom editor:

```
{
   field: "DocumentID",
   title: "Id of document",
   editor: function(container) {
       $('<input class="k-textbox" required name="ProductName" data-bind="value: ProductName">')
          .attr("data-required-msg", "Id of document required")
          .appendTo(container);
   }
}
```

Here is a live demo: http://dojo.telerik.com/@korchev/aHOHO